# Problem with Bluetooth when WiFi usage is high

Tags: drivers, wireless, 20.04, bluetooth, iwlwifi

I have a problem in my Ubuntu 20.04 where when there is high WiFi activity (20mb/s+) the Bluetooth starts to freeze intermittently.

The wireless is connected in 5GHz, so I don't think its a frequency problem.

This problem doesn't happen in windows.

```
lspci -knn | grep Net -A2; lsusb

00:14.3 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Wi-Fi 6 AX201 [8086:06f0]
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device [8086:0234]
    Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
```

```
sudo lshw -class network

  *-network                 
       description: Wireless interface
       product: Wi-Fi 6 AX201
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 14.3
       bus info: pci@0000:00:14.3
       logical name: wlp0s20f3
       version: 00
       serial: 08:5b:d6:b8:8c:60
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=5.8.0-49-generic firmware=55.d9698065.0 QuZ-a0-jf-b0-55.u ip=192.168.0.60 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:16 memory:c7498000-c749bfff
```

```
iwconfig

wlp0s20f3  IEEE 802.11  ESSID:"redacted 5G"  
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:5.745 GHz  Access Point: redacted:03   
          Bit Rate=866.7 Mb/s   Tx-Power=22 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:on
          Link Quality=64/70  Signal level=-46 dBm  
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:33   Missed beacon:0
```

Comment: Are you sure you are using the 5 ghz band?

Comment: @David yes, added the `iwconfig` output